# How do I make an element go under a table-cell in the same div with display: table?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a chat application, and am using display: table and table-cell to get the chat to come in from the bottom. I need a way to enter text below the chat, but my text entry refuses to wrap under the chat's table-cell.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
<div class="chat-window">
    <div class="chat">
        <div class="chat-message">Hi</div>
    </div>
    <div class="text-input">
        <textarea></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.chat-window {
    display: table;
}

.chat {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    width: 100%;
}

.text-input {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The 2nd div refuses to go beneath the first one, even though they've both got their width set to 100%. Is there any way I can make it do it regardless of the first div's display setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to change the styling of the first div, you can set the `display` of the class `text-input` to `table-row`.

```css
.text-input {
    display: table-row;
    width: 100%;
}
```